# TradingView - Incorrect for statement, Expecting to expression

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I am trying to create a loop to print all Kukoin exchenge pairs.

But an error is displayed. How can I fix this problem?

> Incorrect for statement, Expecting to expression

```
//@version=5
study("EMA 89 EMA 200 Kucoin Alerts")
exchange = input("Kucoin")

symbols = syminfo.ticker

for i = 1 to #symbols
    symbol = symbols[i]
    security(exchange,symbol,60)
    ema89 = ema(close, 89)
    ema200 = ema(close, 200)
```

Comment: Almost nothing here makes sense.

Comment: [Here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/) is the reference manual and [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/index.html) is the user manual for you.

Comment: Also, you cannot do what you want. You can only have 40 security calls in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pine script doesn't work like that.

In pine script, you can execute a script on a specific chart which has only one ticker. You cannot execute the script on multiple tickers at a time, and you can't execute a script on all tickers of one exchange (since it is still more then one ticker).

You can, if you want, receive data from other tickers to you current ticker using the `request.security()` function (which on older versions of pine script was just `security()`) but keep in mind you have some limits, most noticeable:

1. You can get the data from the other tickers, but you can't execute the script itself on those other tickers.
2. There is a limit of 40 calls per script.

If you're looking to use the TradingView data for some kind of a screener, consider the above limitations.